# What is the difference between + and - signs in superpositions of quantum states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, probability

What is the difference between states

$$ \frac1{\sqrt{2}} |11\rangle+\frac1{\sqrt{2}} |00\rangle $$

and

$$ \frac1{\sqrt{2}} |11\rangle- \frac1{\sqrt{2}} |00\rangle~? $$

They will all eventually mean probabilities. So what difference does it make?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This question gets to the heart of what makes quantum mechanical amplitudes different from classical probabilities. It is true that if you make measurements in the basis of states $\{\lvert 00 \rangle ,\lvert 11 \rangle\}$ then the two states have the same measurement statistics, and so cannot be distinguished. The interesting thing is that it is possible to measure *in other bases*. In particular, there exists a measurement in the basis $\{(\lvert 00 \rangle\ + \lvert 11 \rangle)/\sqrt{2},(\lvert 00 \rangle\ - \lvert 11 \rangle)/\sqrt{2}\}$ which can perfectly distinguish the two states.

Note that this issue has nothing to do with entangled or two-particle states in particular. Exactly the same could be said of the states $$\lvert \pm\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( \lvert 0\rangle \pm \lvert 1 \rangle ).$$
These states are indistinguishable when measured in the $\{ \lvert 0\rangle,\lvert 1 \rangle\}$ basis, but perfectly distinguishable in the $\{ \lvert +\rangle,\lvert - \rangle\}$ basis.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a base of vectors, in your case $\{ |1,1\rangle, |1,0\rangle, |0,1\rangle, |0,0\rangle \} $ you assign to each vector some phase, e.g. the vector $|1,1\rangle$ has a certain phase that you don't mention explicitly outside the bra-kets. Now, in your calculi you may have superpositions of these vectors of the form

$|\psi\rangle = ae^{i\alpha} |1,1\rangle + be^{i\beta}|1,0\rangle + ce^{i\gamma}|0,1\rangle + de^{i\delta}|0,0\rangle,$

with $a, b, c, d$ positive numbers, i.e. besides the intrinsic phases of the four vectors, they appear in the superposition with complex amplitudes. Thus the amplitude of $|0,0\rangle$ has a difference of phase in comparison with the amplitude of $|1,1\rangle$ and this difference is $\delta - \alpha$.

Returning to your functions, in the first superposition the vectors $|1,1\rangle$ and $|0,0\rangle$ are in phase, while in the 2nd superposition they are in anti-phase, there is a difference $\delta - \alpha = \pi$ between them, i.e. you can write

$ \frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i \cdot 0} |1,1\rangle + \frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i\pi}|0,0\rangle$
.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between those two states is in their phase $|\psi(\alpha)\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|11\rangle+\exp[i\alpha]|00\rangle)$ for $\alpha=2\pi$ you have the first one and for $\alpha=\pi$ you have the second one with the minus sign. Phsycally the difference lies in the interference pattern you might see once you compute the probability amplitudes, meaning $p_{\alpha}=\langle\psi(\alpha)|\psi(\alpha)\rangle=1$ if we define $p_{\alpha\beta}=\langle\psi(\alpha)|\psi(\beta)\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(1+\exp[i(\beta-\alpha)])$ you can see now that by varying $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you can adjust the degree of orthogonality of the two state vectors, for example if $\beta-\alpha=\pi$ the two states are orthogonal and $p_{\alpha\beta}=0$ in such case they make a base you can use for performing measures! Instead if they are not completely orthogonal there is a non zero statistical correlation between the two, meaning there is a non zero probability for one to interfere with the outcome of a measure of the other in an interferometric experiment: for istance take the two states  $\psi(\alpha)$ and $\psi(\beta)$  and make them go through two different branches of an interferometer (a mach-zender maybe) than perform a measure at the end of it after the two states have interfered, what you will find in the computational basis $\{|00\rangle,|11\rangle\}$ (which you can think as the polarization $\{HH,VV\}$) is that the two states $\psi(\alpha)$ $\psi(\beta)$ by having non zero $p_{\alpha\beta}$ will affect the polarizations count of each other giving rise to interference patterns in such counts!

Answer (score 0):

Mostly likely you would see $$|01\rangle+|10\rangle$$ vs. $$|01\rangle-|10\rangle$$ since they have same Eigenvalue for energy and hard to distinguished unless there are another measure to tell the difference. $|00\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$ are very different in this sense.